# On some devices ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE doesn't show the chooser

Tags: android, android-intent, storage-access-framework

I use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to allow the user to choose a path and get SAF permissions, but intent `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`on some user devices results in messages like

> No app available to complete this action

and similar messages or the opening of an empty activity chooser.

The API level of the affected users OS are between API level 23 and 25 (at the moment).

I thought this was an operation supported by default on Android versions above Lollipop, but seems I was wrong.

Is there any alternative other than bloat the App with a double file management one based on SAF and one based on the classic direct file-system access?

Comment: "The API level of the affected users OS are between API level 23 and 25 (at the moment)" -- your results will be based more on manufacturer and device type. For example, [Android TV devices do not always support SAF](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71327396), and I imagine Wear OS devices are similarly constrained. Supposedly, [SAF compliance is included in the CTS for handheld devices](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71327396#comment5), but that also means that SAF is hit-or-miss on devices outside of the Google Play ecosystem. What specific models are giving you trouble?

Comment: @CommonsWare The issue happens on some users that tried the app on TV Boxes and Car infotainment I don't remember the specific model

Comment: I am not surprised that you are encountering SAF issues there. Unfortunately, other than "don't support those devices" (via `<uses-feature>` manifest elements), your options are largely non-existent AFAIK. There isn't even a reliable way to detect whether SAF is supported -- Xiaomi Mi Box pops up a message like that, and it comes from a stub activity that Xiaomi put there in place of real SAF. That is why I filed the issue that I linked to in the first place. While I am less appalled by SAF than you are, this is one specific area where Google seriously screwed up IMHO.

Comment: @CommonsWare So with with the long time complained fragmentation problem they had the "brilliant" idea of creating new optional functions that anyone can decide whether or not to insert at will, first, and then with an even more "brilliant" idea they make them mandatory. WTF

Comment: omg, this is insane. SAF is really mandatory to work with files right now, especially implementing something like video recorder apps with loop recording. But if many car head units don't even support then it's a real fail

Answer (score 0):

I hope it happens only for older version of Android which still can work with `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

In this case we still can work with `SAF` and its `DocumentFile`

`Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).canBeHandled(packageManager)`

```
fun Intent.canBeHandled(packageManager: PackageManager): Boolean {
    return resolveActivity(packageManager) != null
}
```

If `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` is not supported then you can ask users to grant `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, select some folder (`File`) to work with and then convert it to `DocumentFile` using `DocumentFile.fromFile(File)` and returned `DocumentFile` will have Write permission just like `File` but it only works for devices which still fully support `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

So all other logic in your app can be implemented using `DocumentFile`. The problem is just getting initial parent folder to work with (only in this case you will need `File` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` if `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` is not supported)

> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is deprecated (and is not granted) when
> targeting Android 13+

p.s. we can use `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` up to Android 12 (SDK 32) with `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` flag for application at the manifest